# JTable always using fixed size

Tags: java, swing, jscrollbar

I have a JTable which has scroll pane. Scroll pane is added to JTabbedPane. JTabbedPane is added to JPanel which is in JFrame. 
Problem is JTable should occupy entire space width but JTable always places in center and other components gets added to its right. If I make JTable occupy entire width by using     `table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());`
scrollbar is not visible. How to make JTable occupy entire space and other components getting added to its bottom?

Answer (score 1):

> If I make JTable occupy entire width by using
>   table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

This is for `JTable` with a few, fixed rows and columns, or in the case that on apps startup is there intialized `JTable` with fixed number of rows and columns.

---

> How to make JTable occupy entire space and other components getting
>   added to its bottom?

and your comment

> Using Grid Layout videopanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(1,1));

- change `GridLayout` to `BorderLayout` (by assuming that there is `JPanel` placed in `Tab`)
- put `JScrollPane` (contains `JTable`) to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` area
- put other `JComponent`s to separate `JPanel`, this `JPanel` (contains other `JComponent`s) put to the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` area.

Answer (score 0):

Which layout are you using to place component on JPanel.

please have a look into the following URL

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Using Grid Layout 
    videopanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(1,1));